# Java do While loop help me understand

Tags: java

Why does this give me 10 and not 8 as the answer?

```
int count = 0;
do{
    System.out.println("welcome to java");

}while (count++ < 9);
System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: It checks `count < 9` before it adds one to it. So its sees thats its 8, adds one, sees that its 9, adds one and breakd the loop. Thus making 10

Comment: Look at the `++` operator for more details.

Comment: Terrible title. Stack Overflow is not a bulletin board. Please edit your title to prescient summarize your issue.

Answer (score 3):

First, the loop ends when the condition is no longer satisfied.

Secondly `count++` means get the value of `count` and use it in evaluation and only after that increment `count` by `1`.

In other words for `7`, `7 < 9` is satisfied and `count` is incremented to `8`.
For `8` `8 < 9` is satisfied and `count` is incremented to `9`.
For `9` `9 < 9` is not satisfied and loop exits, but before that `count` is still incremented to `10`.

Therefore after exiting the loop `count` is `10`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you understand these 2 basic concepts here :-

1) The code in the do loop gets executed first **before** the expression is evaluated

2) The postfix increment (*count*++) and prefix increment (++*count*) can change the outcome of an expression. Postfix increment (*count*++) increases the value of *count* by one **but only after** *count* is used in the expression.

So, if you instead use prefix increment (++*count*) in your code, the value of *count* will be increased by one right away when it is used in the expression.

Just change your expression from `count++ < 9` to `++count < 8` then you will get the do loop executed 8 times instead.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the last comment, you have a loop that is asked to do something then increment after its first do cycle. The key thing to remember is that it will Do before it increments and check if the while conditions are met. This can be changed by adjusting the code from 9 to 8 as so:

```
int count = 0;
    do{
        System.out.println("welcome to java");
    }while (count++ < 8);
    System.out.println(count);
```

1. This will first println(), then look at count see if it is less then
   8, which is at 0, increment and continue.
2. This will println(), then look at count see if it is less then 8, which is at 1, increment and continue.
3. This will println(), then look at count see if it is less then 8, which is at 2, increment and continue.
4. This will println(), then look at count see if it is less then 8, which is at 3, increment and continue.
5. This will println(), then look at count see if it is less then 8, which is at 4, increment and continue.
6. This will println(), then look at count see if it is less then 8, which is at 5, increment and continue.
7. This will println(), then look at count see if it is less then 8, which is at 6, increment and continue.
8. This will println(), then look at count see if it is less then 8, which is at 7, increment and continue.
9. Finally, it will println() to look at count see if it is less then 8, which is at 8, and end.